# String validation using REGEX

Tags: java, regex

Have searched for my solution on google and finally decided to post a question here.

My requirement is  to send only A C and R characters as input and the maximum length of the string passed should not be more than 6 characters.

Following are the valid states:

A,C,R,

A,R,C,

R,A,C,

R,C,A,

C,R,A,

C,A,R,

R,C,

C,R,

A,R,

R,C,

A,

......

and so on. All possible combinations of A, C, R, are possible but the maximum lenght should not increase 6 char.

So far I am able to perform pattern validation like ([ACR],)+ but also want to perform size validation in same regex.

So for now, I'm using condition like

```
if(!status.matches("([ACR],)+") || status.length()>6){
SOP
}
```

This implementation of size I have to use across multiple methods.

Thanking in advance.

Comment: This is very easily found with google. You need to improve your searching technique.

Comment: Are the commas considered as chars? Should the string ends with a comma?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This regex will allow a pattern to be repeated between 1 and 3 times (in this case the pattern is a dot, i.e. any character):

```
.{1,3}
```

Replace the dot with any regex. In your case `([ACR],)`

In other words: replace the `+` with `{1,3}`

Comment: Replacing the + with {1,6} will allow up to 12 chars, not 6 since the group contains 2 chars

Comment: it would be 3 for my case , after executive hit and run , this is a combination I found , that solves my problem  ^([ACR],){1,3}$

Comment: @GuillaumePolet Yes, it gives the number of times the pattern is allowed to be repeated. Edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
([ACR],){1,3}
```